Science fiction movie where people connect to virtual reality by plugging a device in their neck
I'm trying to remember the title of a movie. I have a vague memory of it so I can't provide much more details. The style and quality was from the 80s or 90s.
In the story people confuse virtual reality with the real world. It happens in the future. They invented a way for individuals to experiment virtual reality by connecting them to a device plugged into their spinal cord (in the neck). The system fits well "like if it has been planed by nature". Some people try to kill each other.
That's all I can remember.
edit: it's not a post-apocolyptic movie. It's not matrix, or Mindwarp.

The description sounds a lot like Matrix, but considering how well-known that movie is, I doubt that this is the one you are talking about.

Kinda seems like eXistenZ starring Jude Law, however it was released in 1999 and also i'm not so sure about the neck plugging thing. I'll post an answer with the detailed similarities in a few moments.

If you recall anything else, however trivial, please add it in (like what the real world was like there, what the actors looked like, specific scenes etc.); At the moment, a lot of these are tropes quite common in VR movies. I have a couple of ideas but not confident about any of them.

So @Guillaumle Combot any feedback ?

@yondaime008 I apologize for the long delay! It seems to be eXisteZ, but I'm not sure, this movie seems to be an action one, the one I remember (well I guess) look more calm, and more basic in term of special effects (I don't). I'll watch it and let you know (it might take some time). It was definitely not matrix or mindwrap: the story was very basic.

@Philipp it's not matrix, but that could have been, thanks!

Sounds an awful lot like Ghost in the Shell (1995), (especially the manga 1991-) but that is animated. The manga goes into technical details about how the interface(s) work that has a sort of natural/organic feel to it. Implanted memories that the individual thinks are actual memories is basically the plot (or a subplot) of the movie. Beware that the manga is potentially NSFW.

The back-of-neck connection concept in the Matrix was taken from GITS. As was the green-text rain device. ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsiepGvjjTM )

@Yorik it wasn't, but the story of this one looks interesting, I'll try to watch it. I just discovered the meaning of "NSFW", good laugh! What kind of movies aren't NSFW where you live?!

Well, technically, all movies are NSFW, since I'm working :) It is a slow movie, kind of like Blade Runner and it is very influential (also like Blade Runner). Kind of violent (not a movie for young kids) and has some odd moments of Philosophy.

Seems like David Cronenberg's eXisteZ (1999) starring Jude Law and Jennifer Jason Leigh.
The movie revolves on the idea of a new virtual reality video game that is being tested on a test group, but soon, the simulation diverges and the quest to find the reality becomes urgent. 
The device used in the movie changes along the realities the players are currently in and there are quite a few scenes where they plug the device to their spines and necks. 
There was a manhunt involved for a reason I truly forgot. It also was released in 1999 which fits your 80-90s criteria.

The manhunt was either part of the game or real life Luddites; at each level they wanted to kill the game designer. But the device was not plugged in at the neck but much lower, at waist level. And I don't think it was "like if it has been planed by nature". It was quite artificial, in fact it was an external controller. But once in the game there was no trace of that left.

I totally agree with you @his there are quite a few differences, it has been a while since I last watched this one, but it rang a bell with the OP description that's why I suggested it.

yonday0088 that might be the closest one, I'll check

@yondaime008 yes that was this one, thanks a lot!

@GuillaumeCombot My pleasure mate, glad I could help :)

Mindwarp is also a possibility, as it has virtual reality and neck ports as an interface. There is also a strong element of "is it the real world or a simulation" in the story.  To narrow it down, do you remember any actors or oddball things like a gun that shoots teeth? Either might help narrow it down.

it was not a post-apocolyptic movie, but thanks for your help!

I have been wracking my brain as I recall a similar film to this looked it up again today n that's how I found this post. But have now found this to be an episode of Black Mirror called Playtest.
